# Signed XML SignatureValue element value (hash in base64) contains &#xd

Tags: hash, signature, timestamping

My application is .NET based.
I have signed xml from third-party environment (Java based).
Its signature value base64 string contains carriage return **#xd;**.

```
<SignatureValue>rNNNqGYd4sEuEyOle0sCHHBv4UVrzBcntgxSuzqm7NrRHpD8qxPu1GpxBtcUKr3bJ0YME2J9SgFA&#xd;wsfp/Vd+0g==
```

According to 
[Canonical XML Version 1.1:](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n11/)  *Line breaks normalized to #xA on input, before* parsing

and 
[Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0: End-of-Line Handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed)
I should remove carriage returns from XML before making any actions with its nodes.

I need to calculate SignatureValue element hash in order to add\verify Signature timestamp.
I can`t find any information how to handle carriage returns in XAdES elements values.

If I decide to remove carriage return from base64 before calculating element hash, third-party application can leave it and calculate hash with carriage return in order to verify my hash and vice versa . 
In these cases hashes won`t match.

I also need some levers how to stand my position in such confrontation with third party system.